# Informal way of saying "on the contrary"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> The casual encounters didn't work for me, though. **On the contrary**,
>   each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than
>   before.

The only option I can think of is **no**. Other suggestions?

Comment: You can say "*quite the opposite*", or even "*counterintuitively*", if, before you had started having these liasons, you had *expected* them to be fulfilling.

Comment: Perhaps `actually` or `in reality`works here

Comment: au contraire, mon ami.

Comment: You *could* just leave the phrase out of your second sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ***rather***:

> 3. Used to suggest that the opposite of a previous statement is the case; on the contrary:
>      [sentence adverb]:
>      *There is no shortage of basic skills in the workplace. Rather, the problem is poor management*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rather#rather__7)

Thus your sentence becomes

> The casual encounters didn't work for me, though. Rather, each of them left me emptier than before, and made me feel guilty afterwards.

Comment: This works perfectly fine, except that to me, _rather_ is **more** formal than _on the contrary_.

Answer (score 4):

The first suggestion in Dan Bron’s comment is very good: *quite the opposite* is a more or less fixed expression very common in colloquial speech. I would personally also be very likely to add in an *in fact*, just to enhance the juxtaposition:

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though. **Quite the opposite, in fact:** each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

Another commonly used option would be to simply use *instead*:

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though. **Instead,** each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

Yet another simple option is the *all they did was* construction (though that does make “each of them” very hard to work in):

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though; **all they did was leave** me emptier than before, **make** me feel guiltier than before.

And probably the simplest of all would be *just*, though it does also downplay the opposition a bit and has slightly less ‘oomph’ to it:

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though; each of them **just** left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

As a side note, while I do get the rhetoric effect you’re going for with the parallel clauses, I don’t think it works particularly well here. If it were me, I’d just get rid of it and simplify to a single clause (using the last version as an example):

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though; each of them **just** left me feeling emptier and guiltier than before.

Comment: ‘. . . *just the reverse . . . ’* works well too

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, with _just/quite the reverse/opposite_, all the possible combinations work about equally well.

Answer (score 3):

There are lots of formal ways of registering an alternative.

A simple informal method would be to, instead of replacing the term, rework it with 'but':

> (blah blah casual encounters are great blah blah)... **but** they didn't work for me. Each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

'but' really means 'and here's an alternative in the other direction'

Comment: I'd put a semicolon or comma after "But they didn't work for me".  suggested edits have to be longer than 6 chars, though :/

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is strictly correct usage, so it'd be best to still use "on the contrary", or "rather", or some of the answers' ideas, if that matters.  But in informal writing, or especially spoken, I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 2):

I can easily substitute the word "**actually**", not just for "on the contrary", but "in fact" as well, to make the sentence less formal:

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though. **Actually**, each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

But reordering the sentence to omit the first comma simplifies things even more, and makes it seem less formal to my eye:

> The casual encounters didn’t work for me, though.  Each of them **actually** left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

> It's just the other way around, each of them left me emptier than before, and made me feel guilty afterwards.

Comment: That does not sound idiomatic to me

Comment: Just the other way around literally implies just the opposite direction, the other way, that you stay on the opposite site of where you want to be.  I have seen it used in fairy tales. Maybe what you think about is the direction of moving, so it sounds awkward to you. I won't argue if it is idiomatic as we are both not native speakers, so it is pointless.

Comment: I understand what you meant. The `Just the other way around` just does not sound like idiomatic English (either BRE or AME) to my admittedly non-native ears. At least I need an `It's` in front

Comment: Yeah, I agree that this way it will be better. Added.

Answer (score 1):

I'd shorten the sentences, because long sentences tend to be more formal:

> The casual encounters didn't work for me, though. **Not at all.** Each
>   of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than
>   before.

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed no-one has mentioned ["conversely"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conversely?s=t) yet.

Adverbial form of:

> **Converse** Adjective
>
> 1. opposite or contrary in direction, action, sequence, etc.; turned around.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

E.g. The casual encounters didn't work for me, though. Conversely, each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

Answer (score 0):

In informal, spoken AmE, the most common equivalent of *"on the contrary"* is the word, ***bullshit***:

The salesman assured me that the suit was black; ***bullshit,*** it was navy blue.

In your construction, it would be used like this:

The casual encounters didn't work for me, though. ***It was bullshit*** - (Yes, the singular "it") each of them left me emptier than before, made me feel guiltier than before.

It's crude; but widely used and accepted. (US)

Comment: Bullish for me carries the slight connotation of deception. So you have believed, that the casual encounters will work for you.

Comment: I agree with @speedyGonzales, 'bullshit' means something very different than 'on the contrary'. 'Bullshit means that you think they are intentionally saying things you know are not the case. 'on the contrary' just registers a difference of opinion.

Comment: This definitely changes the meaning of the original statement. Your sentence implies that someone misled him into believing that casual encounters would work.

Comment: While "bullshit" can indicate deception, it is also used in the sense that something did not live up to expectations - a waste of time, money, emotions,etc.:  "I paid $500 for that self-defense course; but it was bullshit."  "The meeting was called to address the issues that have come up lately; but it was bullshit - they just talked about the VP coming to visit."